# python / os.system : how to keep current environment variables of an executable

Tags: python, compiler-errors, environment-variables, sudo, os.system

Sorry if I didn't find another post related to my issue.

I have a binary "`class`" that I launch with current environment of my SHELL and the execution is fine : `$ ./class params.ini`

But things come complicated when I try to execute it from `os.system` :

Indeed, I get :

```
>>> os.system('./class params.ini')
dyld[38384]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libmkl_intel_lp64.2.dylib
  Referenced from: <53D32B9F-B970-3385-9B2F-304FA4654A63> /Users/fab/Phd_2019_2020/Travail_3_Alain_Injection_des_Biais_Spectro_dans_XSAF_avec_GCph_plus_WL_plus_XC_et_rajout_dun_Prior_dans_la_matrice_de_Fisher_de_SpecSAF_15_JANVIER_2020/MAIN_DIRECTORY_11_BINS_AND_INJECTION_BINS_FROM_GCph_INTO_GCsp/TotallySAF_Alpha_COMPUTE_ERROR_ON_SQUARED_RATIO_BIAS_SPECTRO_BIAS_PHOTO/XSAF_C/CLASS/class
  Reason: tried: '/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.2.0/mac/bin/intel64/../../compiler/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.2.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.2.0/mac/bin/intel64/../../compiler/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.2.dylib' (no such file), '/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.2.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.2.dylib' (no such file), '/../compiler/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.2.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/../compiler/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.2.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.2.0/mac/bin/intel64/../../compiler/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.2.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2022.2.0/mac/bin/intel64/../../compiler/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.2.dylib' (no such file), '/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.2.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.2.dylib' (no such file), '/../compiler/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.2.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/../compiler/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.2.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.2.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libmkl_intel_lp64.2.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
6
```

I know I could add `libmkl_intel_lp64.2.dylib` to `rpath` on the binary by doing a :

```
$ install_name_tool -add_rpath [new_path_rpath] [binary]
```

But isn't there another simpler solution ? for example, integrate it into `~/.startup.py` init file ?

From a general point of view, why my current environment of variables is not kept when I launch an executable from a python script with `os.system(./executable)`

It seems that before an update from my part, the environment variables were transfered to `os.system` in my python script before, but this is no more the case.

Maybe the issue is that I build the executable and installation with `sudo` ( `sudo -H make` or `sudo -E make` could help me ?)

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: use subprocess instead of os - https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html ?

Comment: Even the docs for os.system() say: > The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function.